# java jvax inject fail with nullpoint NullPointerException

Tags: java, maven, dependency-injection, inject

I try to use dependency injections in my project. I make something wrong, but i can not see my failure.

My project setup:

```
Maven main project
|-- maven module "model"
  |-- org.inject.test.model
    |-- Address.java
    |-- User.java
  |-- org.inject.test.model.manger
    |-- UserManager.java
|-- maven module "core"
  |-- org.inject.test.core
    |-- MyMain.java
 |-- org.inject.test.core.managerImpl
   |-- UserManagerImpl.java
```

Address.class:

```
package org.inject.test.model;

public class Address {

    private String street;

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }
}
```

User.class:

```
package org.inject.test.model;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.inject.test.model.manager.UserManager;

@Named
public class User {

    private String name;
    private Address address;

    @Inject
    private UserManager usermanager;

    public User (String name) {
        this.name = name;
        address = null;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        if (address == null) {
            address = usermanager.getAddress();
        }
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

User Manager Interface:

```
package org.inject.test.model.manager;

import org.inject.test.model.Address;

public interface UserManager {

    public Address getAddress ();
}
```

User Manager Impl:

```
package org.inject.test.core.managerImpl;

import javax.inject.Named;

import org.inject.test.model.Address;
import org.inject.test.model.manager.UserManager;

@Named
public class UserManagerImpl implements UserManager {

    public Address getAddress() {
        // Do the DB stuff here (DB.getAddress...)
        Address address = new Address();
        address.setStreet("My test street");

        return address;
    }
}
```

MyMain Class:

```
package org.inject.test.core;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.inject.test.model.Address;
import org.inject.test.model.User;
import org.inject.test.model.manager.UserManager;
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld;
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer;

public class MyMain {

    @Inject
    UserManager usermanager;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // run everything in a weld container (we need someone who manages our injects)
        Weld weld = new Weld();
        WeldContainer weldContainer = weld.initialize();
        MyMain mymain = weldContainer.instance().select(MyMain.class).get();

        mymain.printUser();
    }

    private void printUser() {
        // Working inject
        System.out.println("Working inject: " + usermanager.getAddress().getStreet() + "\n");

        // Not working inject in the user class
        User myuser = new User("nobody");
        System.out.println("Username: " + myuser.getName() + "\n");

        try {
            Address address = myuser.getAddress();
            String streetname = address.getStreet();
            System.out.println("User Street: " + streetname + "\n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e + "\n");
        }

    }

}
```

This my lets say small test project.
My Problem here is that the `@Inject` in the User class does not work.
In the `getAddress()` function I get an `java.lang.NullPointerException`.
But the `@Inject` in the `MyMain` class works.

I have uploaded the whole maven project:
http://www.file-upload.net/download-9979514/inject_test.zip.html

Run it with `mvn clean verify`

Output is something like this:

```
[...]
556 [org.inject.test.core.MyMain.main()] WARN org.jboss.weld.interceptor.util.InterceptionTypeRegistry - Class 'javax.ejb.PostActivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled
556 [org.inject.test.core.MyMain.main()] WARN org.jboss.weld.interceptor.util.InterceptionTypeRegistry - Class 'javax.ejb.PrePassivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled
Working inject: My test street

Username: nobody

java.lang.NullPointerException

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] test .............................................. SUCCESS [0.739s]
[INFO] test-model ........................................ SUCCESS [2.539s]
[INFO] test-core ......................................... SUCCESS [1.851s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `User myuser = new User("nobody");`, you are creating a new instance and not using a managed instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
User myuser = new User("nobody");
```

You are creating a new instance that the injection container does not know about.